navigator.credentials.get should fail if no passkey found
I'm here talking about a scenario when a user has already signed up with passkey and now using another device to login to their account. I saved their credential_id and public_key in the database for Device A but there is no passkey on Device B.
When user enters their email address to login, I check all the devices for that user and pass a challenge with publicKey.allowCredentials array filled with Device A's data. This is passed to navigator.credentials.get but as there are no passkeys, windows presents a dialog to select another device.

Is it possible for credentials.get to throw an error instead, saying no passkey was found ? I want to handle the case differently. Or is there another method that could check if any of the public keys I have is present on the device?

Did you read the documentation on the navigator.credentials.get method? I suspect the options parameter, with the value of "silent" for the mediation property, is exactly what you're asking for.

I tried all values of mediation but same result. Maybe windows doesn't behave correctly?

Tested on Mac, it behaves the same too. Mediation has no effect,

You should probably include all this information you're including in the comments, plus on your user agent (Web browser) and how you're invoking navigator.credentials.get. I don't see an apparent mistake from what you're telling, but others may be able to help better.

I managed to get it working by modifying the publickey options that I'm passing to get. I was earlier using all possible transports but I changed that to internal only. Now get throws an exception. Then I send another request to handle my case. I don't know if this is an answer but I'd mention it here in case it helps someone.


Is it possible for credentials.get to throw an error instead, saying no passkey was found ? I want to handle the case differently. Or is there another method that could check if any of the public keys I have is present on the device?

No on the web, no, for privacy reasons. iOS and Android do offer this for installed apps, however, via preferImmediatelyAvailableCredentials.
On the web the "conditional UI" allows for integration with autofill so that users without credentials aren't bothered by the modal dialog.

As it has been pointed out already this is not possible on the web.
You can circumvent the problems partially if you ask for the identifier first, e.g., the email address of the user. Then, you could run some sort of detection based on the operating system and browser combination, along with the existing passkeys in your database for this identifier, to find out if the passkey is likely to be available on the client (existing and accessible).
Some security considerations come with this, but the customer login of Google is a very good place to study an intelligent implementation for passkeys.
